# SlidingDrawer cannot have UNSPECIFIED dimensions

Tags: android

Hi I am getting a run time exception:

```
SlidingDrawer cannot have UNSPECIFIED dimensions
```

From the below XML, Can any help on this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/scroll" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="10px" android:background="@drawable/formbg">


 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/label" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Question Title" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
              />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/entry" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textColor="#000000"   
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
              />

 </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:paddingRight="0px" > 

   <TextView android:id="@+id/pass" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Type Description" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
    />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/passentry" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="100px" 
              android:textColor="#000000"   
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
              />

   </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/labelbounty" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Enter Amount  $" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px" 
               />

     <EditText android:id="@+id/bounty" 
              android:numeric="decimal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
               />          


   </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">



   <TextView android:id="@+id/duedatelabel" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Due Date" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px" />

  <Button android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
   android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
        android:text="Select Due Date"/>

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">


     <TextView android:id="@+id/labelprimary" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Category" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
               />

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/primarycategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="15px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px" 
    /> 
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout5" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/labelsecondary" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Sub Category" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
     android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
               />

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/secondarycategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/secondary_category"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="15px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px" 
    />              
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout6" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:paddingRight="10px" android:paddingLeft="10px">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Add Attachment"
    >

    </Button>

    </LinearLayout>


     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout7" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:paddingRight="10px" android:paddingLeft="10px">


    <Button android:id="@+id/askNow" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Post Question" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout8" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:orientation="vertical">


         <SlidingDrawer  android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton" android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:topOffset="50dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton" android:background="@drawable/closearrow"></Button>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentLayout"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center" 
                            android:background="#FF444444">
            <Button android:id="@+id/asknew" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Ask New Question"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/logout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Log Out"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </android.view.SurfaceView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same issue so I went digging in the source code.  The basic answer is that something called `measure()` on your SlidingDrawer using `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`, i.e. the SlidingDrawer is allowed to set its own size.

It could be caused by the containing layout (or its parents) being base-aligned or having `WRAP_CONTENT` as its height or width.  If the containing LinearLayout has `baselineAligned` set true, it asks all its children for their size to find the largest one.  And of course it also asks its children for their size if it's supposed to wrap them.

Set `android:baselineAligned="false"` in any LinearLayout that contains the sliding drawer and ensure that nothing containing the SlidingDrawer has WRAP_CONTENT for height or width.  In other words, the SlidingDrawer must have an exact size defined, which means its parents must also if you use `FILL_PARENT`.

Comment: You make it sound like there is some way to avoid the real issue. Base alignment has nothing to do with anything, and neither does wrap_content. He's got a vertical drawer in a vertical LinearLayout, there will never be a "dynamic" way of setting it's height because the layout he is using will grow larger by design. He needs to add the height of the buttons he has in the drawer to the one he's using for the handle and use that value as the layout_height of the drawer, width can remain dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

Because your SlidingDrawer is in ScrollView. My guess is, because ScrollView is unable to provide height, but SlidingDrawer inherit the height from ScrollView, and caused the exception to throw. (I get the clue from http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java)

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a dimension for layout_height attribute, like `android:layout_height="100dp"`

Comment: i had to specify the layout_width also to a specified size

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually sure why this is causing your height or width values to be unspecified, but I can tell you that wrapping your sliding drawer in a LinearLayout is probably causing the problem.  Turn this code into attributes on the `SlidingDrawer` and remove the `LinearLayout`:

```
android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout8" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Hopefully this fixes it for you.

Comment: Just noticed that you have the whole thing wrapped in a scrollview. You should probably have your RelativeLayout as the parent of the view and the scrollview wrapping the things you need to scroll (everything above the SlidingDrawer). One way to test this if none of this works is to simplify the layout so all there is is a couple of views and your scrollview - then you'll be able to narrow down what's causing the error. Oh, keep my original fix in by the way - that's the way it should be done. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the issue might be with ScrollView: Seems like you can't place a SlidingDrawer in a ScrollView. Check out [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/115405) for the same issue. The guy's solution was to have the ScrollView Wrap everything EXCEPT the SlidingDrawer. Then he put both, the ScrollView and the SlidingDrawer into a RelativeLayout - seems to have worked for him, you should give it a shot (as will I).

[EDIT] I gave it a shot and here is how it works for me:

```
        RelativeLayout mainContainer = new RelativeLayout(context);
        mainContainer.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(context);
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        // Add furhter children to scrollview if you wish to
        // Add the scrollview to the main container
        mainContainer.addView(scrollView);
        // Create your SlidingViewer, for instance be inflating it using the layout inflater
        // Inflate from pre-written layout
        // getSystemService is only available from an Activity
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // We dont have the parent view yet, will be added by the layouter
        SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_drawer_layout, null);

        // Add Sliding drawer at the bottom
        mainContainer.addView(new SlidingDrawerWidget(context, new AttributeContainer()).getView());
```

Comment: Okay I tested the above approach and it works, I'll try to update my Post accordingly for more code.